# How to remove color attributes alone in style attributes of HTML and at same time, not to remove color in HTML view content

Tags: html, regex

I want to remove 'color' attribute alone in style attributes of HTML and at same time, not to remove color in HTML view content.

Here, I provided the sample HTML.

### Step 1: Defining regex for html codes range.

```
<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>
```

If I use the above regex pattern expression to select HTML language codes then it selects the content within "<" and ">". Please refer the picture.[selects only html code and not the HTML view content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPoc9.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta content="TX20_HTM 20.0.405.501" name="GENERATOR" />
        <title> well marked style="color:blue;"</title>
    </head>
    <body style="color:red;"> this is atest
</body>
  </html>
```

### Step 2: Defining regex to remove color attributes from HTML coding.

But, within the html attribute contents I want to remove color alone. I have a regex expression to remove the color attributes.

```
(?i)((background-color|color)\:([a-zA-Z0-9#)])[a-zA-Z0-9.(),]+;*)
```

But, the above regex pattern also remove the color from HTML View content as well. Please refer the picture.

[selects all color attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEFyl.png)

**Actually, for my case, the color attributes should not be removed from the HTML View content.**

### Step 3: I want to mix the Step 1 and Step 2 regex

Basically, What I'm trying to mix up these two expressions but, it is not resulting the correct what I expect and I'm not familiar about these expressions..

Please suggest..

which the regex pattern can be used to achieve the above said requirement?

Comment: regexes are not the way to go, use an html/xml parser that supports xpath queries.

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with a regex is a bad idea. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1848654.

Comment: we have limited size of content and hence we go for a regex parse. Any solution on this please?